# React-native placeholder only partially visible on Android

Tags: react-native, textinput

I have a problem with centering a `TextInput`, and at the same time keep the placeholder visible. I want the text to start where the placeholder starts (centered).

On IOS it's working but on android it's only partly visible.

Result on IOS:
[IOS placeholder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwmIM.png)

Result on android:
[Android placeholder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KakGG.png)

This is my code:

```
render() {
return (
  <View style={styles.containerStyle}>
    <TextInput
      underlineColorAndroid='transparent'

      placeholder={"Placeholder    "}
      placeholderTextColor={"grey"}
      maxLength={6}
      style={{  fontSize: 30, color: "black",
        justifyContent: "center",  }}
      onChangeText={this.props.onChangeText}
      value={this.props.value.toUpperCase()}
    />
  </View>
);
  }
}

const styles = {
  containerStyle: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    borderRadius: 5,
    borderWidth: 1,
    shadowColor: "#000",
    elevation: 2,
    marginLeft: 5,
    marginRight: 5,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: "center"
  }
};
```

Comment: Have you tried giving a padding of 0 to the text input? Not that it should cause a significant change but text input on android has a padding by default which it doesn't on ios

Comment: I tried to add `padding:0` under the TextInput style. It didn't change anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `flex:1` in your `TextInput` style

```
<View style={styles.containerStyle}>
    <TextInput
      underlineColorAndroid='transparent'

      placeholder={"Placeholder    "}
      placeholderTextColor={"grey"}
      maxLength={6}
      style={{  flex:1, fontSize: 30, color: "black",
        justifyContent: "center",  }}
      onChangeText={this.props.onChangeText}
      value={this.props.value.toUpperCase()}
    />
  </View>
```